# How to set a Picker with a value in its SelectedIndex property

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, picker

I want that when opening a screen that loads a Picker, this control is set with the value "EXPIRED" ("CADUCADOS"), in the following way ...

[image: SetPicker]

The problem is that this picker has other values besides "EXPIRED" ("CADUCADOS") as shown in the following image...

[image: Picker]

The question is how can I set my Picker control to the "EXPIRED" value? , for this I occupy the SelectedIndex property supplied to an attribute of type int in the following way

```
    <!--PICKER-->
            <Picker                       
                    Title="Seleccione un estado" 
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding Index, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListaEstados, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Estado}"      
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEstado}">
            </Picker>
```

My ViewModel.CS:

```
 int index;

  public int Index
        {
            get
            {
                return index;
            }
            set
            {
                if (index != value)
                {
                    index = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Index)));
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the method that fills the Picker with a List of "States" and it is here that I set the value of the Index ...

```
  private void LoadPickerEstados()
        {
            ListaEstados.Clear();

            var caducados = new Estados
            {
                IdEstado = 0,
                Estado = "CADUCADOS",
            };          

            var aprobaryplanificar = new Estados
            {
                IdEstado = 1,
                Estado = "POR APROBAR Y PLANIFICAR",
            };

            var planificar = new Estados
            {
                IdEstado = 4,
                Estado = "POR PLANIFICAR",
            };

            ListaEstados.Add(caducados);
            ListaEstados.Add(aprobaryplanificar);
            ListaEstados.Add(planificar);

         Index = 1;

        }
```

The problem is that when setting Index = 0 => this returns the Placeholder, when setting Index = 1 => it returns For approval and planning ("POR APROBAR Y PLANIFICAR") and when setting Index = 2 => it returns for planning ("POR PLANIFICAR"), but I can never get the value "EXPIRED" ("CADUCADOS")!!

What's going on? Am I using the right property? 
How can I set the picker with the right value? any help for me?

Comment: The default value of an int is 0. So when you set `Index = 0` it won't do anything because `index` is equal to 0 already. This might be the problem. Could you try removing the `index != value` check?

Comment: Can you show your sample project.The problem may be `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` have some conflict using in them.

Comment: Please set SelectedIndex=-1 when you are loading the page.